# How to get HttpContext.Header information from nested methods inside a restful service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a API endpoint in  controller class

```
[HttpPut, Route("urisuffix")]
[Authorization tags]
public async Task PutAPI()
{
   return serviceA.PutSomething();
}


class serviceA
{
  public async Task PutSomething()
   { 
      \\\some code
   }

}
```

My question is if I do HTTPContext.Current inside the PutSomething method of the service, does it give the right headers passed to the API call?

Comment: I think no, because you are running PutSomething on different thread as it is `async`. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks) `This object is only available in the thread controlled by ASP.NET. Usage in background threads could lead to undefined behavior.` I might be wrong here.

Comment: so I guess I'll have to pass it as a paramter I guess.

Comment: Yeah, Thats the simplest and easiest way I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

As other mentioned, the easiest way to pass `HttpContext` as parameter, there is another mechanism in asp.net core for some service to access current context: `HttpContextAccessor`. If some use cases could be useful. You can inject accessor into you service:

```
public class serviceA
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

   public serviceA(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> PutSomething()
   { 
      var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
      
      // Use the context object to access request information
      // Example: var headers = context.Request.Headers;

      return Ok(); // or whatever result you want to return
   }
}

// don't forget to add the accessor in your service collection
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-7.0.

But I wouldn't recommend to use it, because this way shows your application has some problems in layers of concerns. Typically all http related logic should be performed by middleware pipeline and controllers, and service should be not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try inject the IHttpcontextAccessor to service class directly instead of making more parameters.

serviceA.cs

```
    public class serviceA
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public serviceA(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public string PutSomething()
        {
            var b=_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"];
            Console.WriteLine("Accept header in service: "+b);
            return "nothing";
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public ValuesController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }


        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test()
        {
            var a= HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept"];
            Console.WriteLine("Accept header in controller: "+ a);

            var service=new serviceA(_httpContextAccessor);
            return service.PutSomething();
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

As Aleksei suggested, register like below is better.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Test
[image]

Comment: `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` should be used